# Need the correct regex range for finding instances of '@' in the attached code

Tags: regex

I need the correct regex range to find all instances of @@ in the following code:

```
 $TheString['Template1'] = '<h2>
    <strong>
        <strong>
            @@textarea_HEADLINE@@
        </strong>
    </strong>
</h2>
<h4>    
    <strong>
        @@textarea_SUMMARY@@
    </strong>
</h4>
<p>
    @@textarea_DESCRIPTION@@
</p>
<div class="CB"  style="height:10px; clear:both;"></div>
<div id="sum_wrapper" style=" margin: 0 auto; float:left; height:auto; width:auto; ">
    <div id="sum_top" style="border-top: 1px solid #D8D8D8 ; width:auto; height:10px;"></div>
    <div id="Col1" style="width:196px; height:auto; float:left; ">
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; padding:0 8px;">
            <strong>AVG user rating:</strong> <br> @@text_USERRATING@@ <br>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; padding:0 8px;">
            <strong>How Much:</strong> <br>@@text_HOW-MUCH@@<br>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; padding:0 8px;">
            <strong>File Size:</strong> <br>@@text_SIZE@@<br>&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Col2" style="width:198px; height:auto; float:left; border-left: 1px solid #D8D8D8;">
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; padding:0 8px;">
            <strong>Visit:</strong> <br>@@text_VISIT@@<a href="">Developer\'s Website</a><br>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; padding:0 8px;">
            <strong>Version Date:</strong> <br> @@text_UPDATED@@ <br>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; padding:0 8px;">
            <strong>Category:</strong> <br> @@text_CATEGORY@@ <br>&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Col3" style="width:198px; height:auto; float:left; border-left: 1px solid #D8D8D8;">
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; padding:0 8px;">
            <strong>Languages:</strong><br> @@text_LANG@@ <br>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; padding:0 8px;">
            &nbsp; <br>&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word; padding:0 8px;">
            <strong>Works on:</strong> <br> @@text_PLATFORMS@@ <br>&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="CB"  style="height:0px; clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="sum_bottom" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8 ; width:auto; height:10px;"></div>
</div>
    <div class="CB"  style="height:10px; clear:both;"></div>
<strong>Comment:</strong> @@textarea_COMMENT@@';

$TheString['Template2'] = '<h2>
        <div id="header">
<h1>
    @@text_HEADER@@
</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
 @@text_CITY-1@@<br>  

 @@text_CITY-2@@<br>  

 @@text_CITY-3@@<br>  
</div>

<div id="section"">
<h1>CITY of Choice</h1>
<p>
   @@textarea_CITY-SUMMARY@@ 
</p>
<p>
   @@textarea_CITY-REVIEW@@   
</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    Copyright ©   @@text_COPYRIGHT@@  
</div>
```

At the moment I have this:

```
function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $theFullTemplate){
    $matches = array();
    $regex = "/$start([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$end/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $theFullTemplate, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

$textInbetween = getInbetweenStrings('@@', '@@', $theFullTemplate);

which works for all the instances on $TheString['Template1'] but not for all of them on $TheString['Template2'].

I'd appreciate some help,

Thanks

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Am I blind or your two examples are strictly the same?

Comment: You need a `php` reference tag.

Comment: oh darn, made a mistake. The second code is this:
<div id="header">
<h1>
 @@text_HEADER@@
</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">
 @@text_CITY-1@@<br>  
 
 @@text_CITY-2@@<br>  
 
 @@text_CITY-3@@<br>  
</div>

<div id="section"">
<h1>CITY of Choice</h1>
<p>
   @@textarea_CITY-SUMMARY@@ 
</p>
<p>
   @@textarea_CITY-REVIEW@@   
</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
 Copyright ©   @@text_COPYRIGHT@@  
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd want your regular expression to be `/(@@)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(@@)/i`

```
<?php

//Desired regular expression: (@@)[a-z_]+(@@)

function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $theFullTemplate){
    $matches = array();
    $regex = "/(". $start .")[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(". $end .")/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $theFullTemplate, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

https://eval.in/194246

http://regexr.com/39gqa

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6Th

Comment: Your regex doesn't match `-` as OP's one

Answer (score 0):

`@@([^@]*)@@`

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iO1uK1/8